# Embedding not found in MainActivity.java in flutter

Tags: java, flutter, dart

I use method channel for using Java code in flutter but
Flutter activity (flutter.plugin , embedding and some other library's not found)

[image]

Comment: can you try to copy-paste the code and the error in your post instead of the picture?.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshot, I guess you are using vs code.
In general I advise to do the Android/iOS specific parts of flutter in their respective IDEs because of these things.

VSCode does not detect the android libraries by default.